# Liquibase generateChangeLog missing columns statements in mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, liquibase

Using MariaDB 5.5. Liquibase 3.4.0.

Running command below

```
    java -jar pathto\liquibase-core-3.4.0.jar
    --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --url=jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db
    --username=username --password=psw
    --changeLogFile=path\hangelog_init.xml
    --classpath=C:\path\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar generateChangeLog
```

Getting as a result create table statements without columns:

```
    <changeSet author="usr (generated)" id="1438089865463-1">
        <createTable tableName="ABC"/>
    </changeSet>
```

How to fix it? 3.4.0 liquibase already supports maria db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was some broken views..
I exported current sql schema to sql and loaded it on new database. Liquibase was working properly. Then compared two schemas and found dead views. After removing them, generateChangeLog started working properly.